# How to secure the linux boot/efi partition from being tampered by Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I've encrypted my root partition with LUKS and my home partition with ecryptfs, so the data on on them can only be damaged. Problem is, you can easily modify stuff on the boot/efi partition from Windows. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Never put any sensitive data in `/boot/efi`.  You can't encrypt it. The reason being that your system firmware needs to read EFI in order to boot your machine.  If it were encrypted the firmware couldn't access the boot loader.

---

If your system has a TPM then you can use the TPM's "measurements" (PCR registers) to verify that boot components in `/boot/efi` were not tampered with.

TPM's can also store encryption keys for you and be "sealed" (locked) based on the PCR registers.  Then the TPM will "unseal" and allow you to read those encryption keys ***only*** if the boot process was not tampered with.

It's important to be sure which things are measured in which PCRs.  If you don't configure the TPM to include important PCRs then it might unseal despite tampering.

TPMs are not 100% bullet proof.  Theoretically they can be tampered with as a sort of physical man in the middle attack by unsoldering them from the board and placing hardware between them and the motherboard.  This is typically extremely hard but not impossible.

---

As an alternative to measuring absolutely everything (including grub configuration) in PCRs, grub has a `check_signatures` option.  You build an EFI binary containing your own PGP public key and a basic configuration with  that demands all other files loaded by grub must have a digital signature matching the public key.

This way, you digitally sign your kernel, initrd, grub config and verify grub EFI has not been tampered with through a TPM PCR.  This can be little easier to work with because you don't need to fiddle with the TPM every time you make the slightest configuration change to your boot.

---

Since another has suggested it I'll comment on "Secure boot" and explain why not...

Secure boot is a protection for a different purpose. It's more about supply chain verification than anti-tampering on the EFI partition.

It offers some protection (but not absolute protection) against installing things to the early phases of your boot that do not come from a trusted vendor.  Eg: it protects you from being tricked into installing a hacker's boot loader.

It works by signing the binaries via a trusted CA.  By default, most hardware has Microsoft's CA ready installed and various Linux vendors have certificates signed by Microsoft.

It does NOT protect anything that was generated by your laptop as part of install, setup, or configuration.  And it really only verifies that the binary is from a reputable vendor.  It doesn't prevent someone replacing you bootloader with any other bootloader from another reputable vendor or re-configuring yours to do anything at all.  Therefore it really offers next to no protection against EFI tampering.

Answer (score -3):

> Problem is, you can easily modify stuff on the boot/efi partition from Windows. How can I prevent this?

Not if you have secure boot enabled.

Edit: Mr. Philip Couling claims *the "hacker" can change kernel boot arguments and add `init=/bin/bash` which results in a breach* but this attack will plainly not work because the OP has their data encrypted. There's no bash. Even if the hacker used `/bin/bash` from some external location, they would still not be able to do anything because user data is encrypted. In short this "attack" is worthless and simply doesn't work.

Secondly, if the hacker has physical access to your PC which Philip Couling
heavily implied, there are far more dangerous implications and there's nothing you can do to protect yourself. The hacker can simply plant a HW keyboard sniffer or a dozen of other gadgets to access your system without you knowing about that.

Lastly, Windows by itself is more secure than Linux by a very long shot. Linux security is laughable, it's mainly based on obscurity rather than security. For instance, in Linux you only have your kernel and modules digitally signed, while in Windows every running Microsoft binary is signed which allows to make sure your system has not been tampered with. Not to mention other features, like bitlocker, hypervisor-based process isolation, execution group policies, etc. etc. etc.