How to be sure where /boot files originated from for security?
I’m contemplating automatically PGP signing all files in my boot process, from grub config onwards with detached PGP signatures.
This will be used with grub’s check_signatures with a statically built grub stub in /boot/efi/EFI/ containing my own public PGP key.
I want to sign nothing but:

grub config files in /boot/grub generated by the system
Linux kernels installed through apt
initramfs only when generated by the system
Optionally grub modules when installed through apt. These may get compiled into the grub stub. I’m not decided yet.

Im concerned about a relatively trivial evil maid attack that could sneak unsigned files into my unencrypted /boot partition, to get them signed by the automatic process later.

/boot and /boot/EFI will be unencrypted and therefore may be freely written by an “evil maid”.
/ will be encrypted with LUKS and a key stored in the system’s TPM
The key in the TPM will be ceiled with PCRs sufficient to protect

BIOS
Grub stub in /boot/efi/EFI (and this the PGP public key)


I want to be narrow with the scope of this question. Suffice to say that I am making a conscious decision to accept the following calculated risks:

Evil maid attacks which compromise the TPM itself
Compromised APT supply chain leading to malicious dpkg files being installed
Otherwise anything that can inject malicious onto my encrypted drive

Wider discussions of how to use a TPM are off topic here.
Signing for Secure boot os also off topic, it does not help with drive encryption (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752234/20140)

I want to ask how I can ensure that only files installed by apt or generated by my system (as above) are signed, and NOT blindly sign everything in my unencrypted boot partition.
Where should I hook into APT to do this and how to be sure of ignoring files from other origins?

Fedora UKI has got you covered.

I've not heard of this requirement "avoiding enrolling the kernel into TPM PCRs". As of "I’m on an apt based system" well, you can spend literally 200 man hours implementing your own solution only to have it rendered broken with future upgrades of your tooling or/and distro. UKI just works. It's been tested. With UKI your grub config remains open for attacks but it's easy to inspect visually. Just like with Windows where the BCD configuration is not signed.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov I thought I was experiencing Déjà vu. I just realised we had this argument before. No secure boot is unrelated (and unhelpful) to the topic of TPMs and has totally different use cases and protections. UKI will not help with this issue at all. It’s a different topic. If there was an out of the box solution to automatic TPM usage, that may be interesting.
